# Why am I obtaning this strange rendering behavior putting ng-template into an accordion tab?

Tags: angular, primeng, angular-directive, angular-template, ng-template

I am working on an Angular application using PrimeNG and I have the following problem using PrimeNG Accordion.

This is the HTML code of my component:

```
<div class="container">  

    <p-selectButton [options]="editPatientOption"
                    [(ngModel)]="editPatientSelectedOption"
                    (onChange)="editPatientOptionOnChange($event, 5)"></p-selectButton>

    <div *ngIf="editPatientSelectedOption=='info';then info_content else edit_content">here is ignored</div>

    <p-accordion [multiple]="true">

        <p-accordionTab header="ANAGRAFICA PAZIENTE">
            TEST
            <ng-template #info_content>
                INFO
            </ng-template>
        
            <ng-template #edit_content>
                EDIT
            </ng-template>
                
        </p-accordionTab>
    
        <p-accordionTab header="CARTELLA CLICNICA">
            <app-medical-record-add-form></app-medical-record-add-form>
        </p-accordionTab>
        <p-accordionTab header="VALUTAZIONE ESTETICA">
            Content 3    
        </p-accordionTab>
        <p-accordionTab header="CRONOLOGIA TRATTAMENTI SVOLTI">
            Content 3    
        </p-accordionTab>
    </p-accordion>

</div>
```

As you can see I am checking the value of the **editPatientSelectedOption** component property in order to select the related **ng-template**. Then ito the first accordion tab I put these **ng-template** in order to dipslay the content of the selected template into my accordion tab. But this is what happens:

If the **editPatientSelectedOption=='info' it is rendered in this way:

[image]

How can you see the info content (highlited) appears outside of my accordion tab.

Same thing if the **editPatientSelectedOption !='info' it is rendered in this way:

[image]

Why the content of the template is correct (it is the expected one) but is rendered outside the expected place (the accordion tab). What is happening? What am I missing? How can I fix this behavior?

Comment: Listing your version of Angular might be helpful

Comment: it is expected that your template will be rendered in place of div with ngIf. just put that div in place where you need it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems like it's working as expected to me. This is happening because of where your `div` is defined handling the toggling between those templates. For instance, you could move your `ng-template` declarations to anywhere else in that template and you would have the same behavior because where those are defined doesnt matter, but where your `div` using them is defined would matter.

```
 <div *ngIf="editPatientSelectedOption=='info';then info_content else edit_content">here is ignored</div>
```

Move the above to where you want the text to show up and it should work correctly.